Split a string by +
I want to split b into "X1" "+" "X2" using strsplit(). But it gives me something like this when all the letters and characters are separated.
b <- "X1+X2"
strsplit(b, "+")

[[1]]
[1] "X" "1" "+" "X" "2"

Is there a way to detect X1 and X2 and split it into these two only?

You need to escape special characters like +, so strsplit(b, "\\+"). Or use strsplit(b, "+", fixed = TRUE) to not use regular expression at all.
